# QGIS union (one vector layer): side location conflict?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I occurred an error when using "union" tool (only one layer) in QGIS. I have a series of vector files, yet only one vector file fails to union with the error information. The error is:

> GEOS geoprocessing error: intersection failed. TopologyException: side
>   location conflict at ...

I have tried "fix geometry", "check valid", and "v.clean" functions, but none of them works.

The vector file is at the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xF1qezlEtaktXvFSf01PB5QdUPhlQCdS/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the specified location? Is there anything unusual about your layer at that point? If you add a screenshot of the layer at that point, perhaps we can see the issue.

Comment: In my opinion, from the point of view of topological errors, your file is in order, at the specified point the two polygons touch each other, which is observed with other polygons, try to merge on another version of QGIS ... In fact, it is difficult to understand the behavior of polygons, some of them overlap, some touch each other, some partially intersect each other ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I just solved the problem by choosing the whole cleaning tools in the "v.clean" function.